# Handling parentheses in a path in for /f

Tags: windows, batch-file, path, escaping, filepath

**Update: The `for /f` line was a non-issue. In my original code, I had not enclosed `%~2` in quotes when echoing it as follows: `echo.%%f only in %~2`. I simply forgot that the entire `for /f` is parsed at the same time, so I overlooked other possible causes including this actual cause.**

Inside a (recursive) subroutine I have:

```
echo.I really hate this problem: %~2
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b "%~2"`) do (
    echo.Breaks before this echo
```

where `%~2`=`d1 test\same1\fldr (break)\broken` as a test case

Output:

```
I really hate this problem: d1 test\same1\fldr (break)\broken
\broken was unexpected at this time.
```

I assume the error (2nd line of output) happens because the `)` in `d1 test\same1\fldr (break)\broken` is acting as a closing parenthesis for the `(` in `` (`dir /b "%~2"`) ``

Also, I reference `%~2` several other times inside the subroutine, including inside the `for /f` in question, so I really need a more general solution if possible.

**So the question is: How do I force the intended interpretation of `%~2` in `` (`dir /b "%~2"`) `` when `%~2` includes parentheses?**

**Edit:**

Ok, I've reproduced the same output using a small test file based on my real code. This is what caused me to realize that it was an `echo` within the `for /f` causing problems. See the update at the top of this post.

test.bat:

```
echo
call :testSub isMismatch "d1 test\same1\fldr (break)\broken" "d2 test\same1\fldr (break)\broken"
pause
goto:eof

:testSub
echo.I really hate this problem: %~2
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b "%~2"`) do (
    echo.%%f only in %~2
)
```

Output:

```
G:\broken>test.bat

G:\broken>echo
ECHO is on.

G:\broken>call :testSub isMismatch "d1 test\same1\fldr (break)\broken" "d2 test\same1\fldr (break)\broken"

G:\broken>echo.I really hate this problem: d1 test\same1\fldr (break)\broken
I really hate this problem: d1 test\same1\fldr (break)\broken
\broken was unexpected at this time.

G:\broken>      echo.%f only in d1 test\same1\fldr (break)\broken

G:\broken>
```

Comment: Place a `echo on` before the `for` command and see what is being executed. For me (tested) the double quotes in `"%~2"` are protecting the parenthesis and nothing fails.

Comment: @MCND I've updated my post. I also cannot reproduce the issue when I take the problem code out of context, but I also don't see how the context could possibly affect this situation.

Comment: As said, include a `echo on` before the `for` command in your original code to see what the parser is trying to handle.

Comment: @MCND The original output was with echo on. However, I've learned more and updated my post again. Thanks for trying to work through this. Since it is resolved and also sort of a non-issue, maybe this post should be closed or something. I'll let someone else decide and handle that.

Comment: Try `echo.%%f only in "%~2"`.